# Sending special strings with "WriteLn" in "Indy" (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, string, indy

In Indy when we are sending some strings to the server , they change and will be shown in new format . for example i tried to send a binary file(File.exe) with "WriteLn" command in indy :

```
    Ms.LoadFromFile(FileAddress);

    Ms.Read(B, Chunk);

    for j := low(B) to high(B) do
    begin
      Part := Part + chr(B[j]);
    end;
```

and for sending strings :

```
FileClient.IOHandler.WriteLn(Part);
```

when client was sending strings to the server , i was monitoring the clinet with a sniffer . and finally i got this results :

```
MZ?.........yy..,.......@...................................,.....o..?.I!,.LI!This    program cannot be run in DOS mode....$..
```

As you see there are some characters that they are not in their true format any more and they changed to "?" character . but it should be noted that the sniffer automatically changed some string to "." , for example one of this points(".") is chr(0) or chr(5) maybe !!

but the sniffer couldn't change some characters to "." and we see them in "?" format .
for example i open a binary file with notepad and you can see true format :

[alt text http://up.iranblog.com/Files/9f195012dbc2425b8773.png](http://up.iranblog.com/Files/9f195012dbc2425b8773.png)
Anyway , the question is : how can i send a binary file with "WriteLn" command in Indy 10 ?

Comment: What version of Delphi? If D2009+ you are looking at interpretation of your strings as being Unicode where 1 char does _not_ equal 1 byte.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Kermia, the  `WriteLn` procedure is designed to send text data not binary, also adds a CRLF at the end of each mesagge sent.

You can use the `WriteStream` or `Write` procedure to send binary data.

if you insist in use the `WriteLn` procedure, you need to encode the binary data before sending using a [Binary-to-text encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) like [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), and after decode in the server side.

Comment: Agreed, especially since the data is coming from a TStream to begin with.  Indy also has a WriteFile() method available as well, which opens a file and dumps its bytes as-is into the socket.